# How can I arrange my running terminals or command prompts by "tile" in windows 8?

Tags: windows, windows-8, multiple-monitors, tiles

In Windows 7 you could just open the task manager, select multiple running applications, right click and select to tile them in a way like this:

[image: http://cdn.ilovefreesoftware.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/scheme_1.jpg]

In windows 8, it seems you can't do so. Does anyone know a way to do it in Windows 8?

The main reason I am asking this is because I want to view many terminals at once when I am SSH'ing into various machines.

Comment: try to reactivate the old Taskmgr from Win7 and see if this still works: http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-restore-the-good-old-task-manager-in-windows-8/

Comment: I would sadly prefer to keep the current win8 task manager. Thank you for the suggestion though!

Comment: have you at lest tried this? Does it work?

Comment: Just tried it, did not work. I didn't even get anything pop up either via ctrl-shift-esc or the usual ctrl-alt-del and clicking on task manager.

Comment: I use [SuperPutty](https://code.google.com/p/superputty/) to view many terminals at once when SSH'ing into various machines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Effectively, in Windows 8 the Task Manager's Applications tab has lost its Windows menu.
Just another useful option lost in Microsoft's course for Metro.

You can still right-click on an empty Taskbar area and choose "Show Windows Side by Side".
I don't know if Windows 8 has kept the other options of Cascade and Stacked.
As these options work on all the windows, they might do too much for you.

As usual, when Microsoft subtracts, one is obliged to fill the hole with third-party products.
Here are some products that rearrange windows on the desktop
(although I don't know how well they work in Windows 8):

[WindowSlider](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/manage-multiple-windows-windows-7-desktop-windowslider)
[Plumb](http://palatialsoftware.com/plumb/)
[GridMove](http://jgpaiva.dcmembers.com/gridmove.html) - not exactly what you ask for, but still a very interesting concept.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you're not using the [sarcasm]super awesome![/sarcasm] features in the new Task Manager, simply replace it with the old one.

Check this out: http://www.guidingtech.com/18977/get-back-windows-7-task-manager-windows-8/

Comment: Welcome to [su].  This answer needs to be expanded to explain what that link says, in case the link goes down in the future.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to tile windows of one application, and you say you want to tile several SSH terminals, <kbd>Shift</kbd>-right-click the application button on the Taskbar and then click **Show windows side-by-side**.

Comment: Right clicking only gives me this sadly. Are you sure this function exists in windows 8? Since I only remember this being in win7.

http://i.imgur.com/aLui7jZ.png

Comment: @hak8or I forgot `Shift`, now I've edited my answer: Press `Shift` and then right-click.

Answer (score 1):

I have decided to just go with divvy instead. It does not automatically make programs into a grid, but it seems to be the closest I can get for "free" (it is not free, but the maker was nice and made it into nagware). I will probably buy it in the future if I continue to like it.

http://mizage.com/divvy/